# Inputbox, empty input clears cell

Tags: vba, inputbox

I'm trying to make a macro which checks a cell for changes. If the cell changes a user has to provide a date. When cancel is pressed or the field is left blank, another cell should be cleared. When cancel is pressed the cell gets cleared, but when 'ok' is pressed without providing a date I get an error. My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myValue As Date

    If Target.Address = "$E$17" Then

        myValue = Application.InputBox("Geef de revisiedatum op, DD/MM/JJ", "Revisie datum")
        Range("$I$17").Value = myValue
        If myValue = False Then
            Range("$I$17") = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$E$20" Then

        myValue = Application.InputBox("Geef de revisiedatum op, DD/MM/JJ", "Revisie datum")
        Range("$I$20").Value = myValue
        If myValue = False Then
            Range("$I$20") = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add another condition `If myValue = vbNullString Then`

Comment: i still get an error 13: types do not match

Comment: Maybe try: IF LEN(myValue) = 0 THEN

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have myvalue declared as a date.  When no value is returned it is a string that a date can't handle.

Change myValue to a string.  Then your checks for myValue = False will change to If myValue = "" then.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myValue As String

    If Target.Address = "$E$17" Then

        myValue = Application.InputBox("Geef de revisiedatum op, DD/MM/JJ", "Revisie datum")
        Range("$I$17").Value = myValue
        If myValue = "" Then
            Range("$I$17") = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$E$20" Then

        myValue = Application.InputBox("Geef de revisiedatum op, DD/MM/JJ", "Revisie datum")
        Range("$I$20").Value = myValue
        If myValue = "" Then
            Range("$I$20") = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that MatthewD, now it indeed works, however the data is formated to mm/dd/yy. us dutch folks are a bit weird in that we like to have dd/mm/yy format, is there a way to force this?